# Draggable element does not apply border radius correctly in Chrome

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, draggable

Hey I have a simple draggable div that I've given a border radius. However, as soon as I start dragging the element, it still has white corners when the element hovers over itself.  You can test it here (please use Chrome):
https://play.tailwindcss.com/fKiBnLP0A0

This problem only occurs in Chrome but not in Firefox. Could that also be an tailwind problem?

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1):

This is still broken in Chrome. I found that this can be fixed by setting an opacity to the draggable element.

add opacity-95

```html
<div draggable="true" class="flex h-10 opacity-95 w-20 items-center justify-center rounded-full bg-blue-500 text-lg font-medium text-white hover:cursor-pointer">Test</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `transform` for the dragged element.

In this case, I set `skew-x-0` for the draggable element, and it's OK

You can test it here (use any broswer):
https://play.tailwindcss.com/lmtIsx9qTY

Comment: confirmed, this works